# Add Node Modules in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

This is quite a simple question but I cannot find the answer as I want to stick with correct conventions.

How do I include node modules from the "node_modules" folder in my ionic app? I'm not sure if it has anything to do with it being outside the "www" folder.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out Marcus? I'm sitting with the same issue as you..